# how to make multi color gradient in xml for android background?

Tags: android, android-layout

how to make a gradient color background like this in xml android?

Can we make like this background in android?

[image]

Comment: its not a gradient its a image t

Answer (score 0):

The image you provide is not a gradient it's normal image but to make gradient in android you can do this:

1- create new drawable resource file

2-change **selector** to **shape**

3- inside shape u can start creating your gradient like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <gradient
       android:type="linear"
       android:angle="90"
       android:startColor="#f6ee19"
       android:endColor="#115ede" />
</shape>
```